# How to insert data in an on before trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have on before trigger. Lets say i insert a row. Is it posible to insert another row in the trigger  into the same table so there are 2 total rows inserted?

Comment: `insert another row in the trigger` what is this? Clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

If it is on the same table, the answer is a big ***NO***.

If you want to add another duplicate row, it would cause a circular invocation of `BEFORE` trigger. Circular operations on the same table are not allowed in a trigger.
You can only add a new row to another table but not in the same table.

**Refer to**: [***MySQL: Triggers***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)